# Signing Power Point Documents using DocuSign

Tags: digital-signature, docusignapi

As I know word and excel documents have to have a signature line to be signed.

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/dsa/local_02

I've added a signature line to the doc/docx-xls/xlsx documents programmatically.

My question is about for power point. There is no possible to add a signature line in power point (as default). So I can sign these type documents without adding a signature line like Pdf file?

for now I do not have chance to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can digitally sign a powerpoint file (pptx) to assure the recipients that:

- it was indeed created by you, not by someone else (authentication)
- that it has not been changed since you created it (document integrity)
- and that you can't deny that it came from you (non-reputability)

See the [Microsoft docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-remove-a-digital-signature-in-Office-files-70d26dc9-be10-46f1-8efa-719c8b3f1a2d#__toc311526848).

To digitally sign Powerpoint files, you can use the DocuSign Signing Appliance.

As an alternative, you can use Powerpoint to export a pdf version of your deck, and then sign it using the DocuSign Signature service (the cloud product).

Comment: Thank you for your answering. But I mean do i need to do "special things" to sign like adding a signature line. Because I am using the docusign API for that. The process is the same like signing a pdf ?

Comment: My understanding from the Powerpoint docs is that digitally signing a Powerpoint file does not include a visible signature line since there is no natural place to put the graphic representation of the signature. Remember that with digital signatures, the graphical signature representation is NOT needed. What counts is the digital signature itself. 

See the Microsoft docs referenced in my answer.